# How to parse this JSON using JSON.Net?

Tags: c#, json

I cannot retrieve the values inside the queued_messages. Im using C#
Here is the sample JSON data:

```
{
  "queued_messages": 
  [
    "MessageID082420150825111152",
    "MessageID082420150825111153",
    "MessageID082420150825111154"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
string json = httpRequest.message.Trim();

JObject jsonIDs = JObject.Parse(json);

Queued_messages queuedMessageIDs = jsonIDs["queued_messages"].ToObject<Queued_messages>();
```

Class of Queued_messages:

```
  public class Queued_messages
  {
      [JsonProperty("queued_messages")]
      public string queued_messages { get; set; }
  }
```

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Look buddy, "cannot parse the values" means nothing.  How on earth can anyone possibly answer when you did not even bother to say what actually did happen?  Try harder next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queued_messages` must be an array

```
public class Queued_messages
{
    [JsonProperty("queued_messages")]
    public string[] queued_messages { get; set; }
}

JObject jsonIDs = JObject.Parse(json);
Queued_messages queuedMessageIDs = jsonIDs.ToObject<Queued_messages>();
```

Comment: I'd encountered this error
'code' Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'iTxtLiteListener.Queued_messages' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T>that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array 'code'

Comment: @LoudelosReyesII waht is `jsonIDs["queued_messages"]`? is it your original data from first block?